# Is it possible to bulk add titles to an IMDB list?

Tags: imdb

I want to add my movie/TV collection to IMDB lists. The default way to add titles to a list is very cumbersome, so I was wondering if there is a way to import titles from a csv file or something like that so that the process becomes easier.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, it is not possible. As of now, IMDB has no such option. Also, IMDB has no API to make it possible.

Generally speaking, BULK is something every company wishes to avoid.